# Ajuda com precisão em Algoritmos de Machine Learning de Classificação

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, sklearn

Eu estou acompanhando uma aula onde o professor cria um código que irá avaliar 7 diferentes algoritmos classificatórios de Machine Learning e tentei fazer de um jeito mais automatizado para que esses dados já caíssem em um Excel.

Olhando 'por cima' os resultados estão se saindo relativamente parecidos. Porém, percebi que no código do professor, as precisões (accuracy_score) possuiam 4 casas decimais após à vírgula, enquanto a minha tinham apenas 3.

Tentei procurar no código o que pode ter sido feito diferente, porém simplesmente não consegui achar, os meus valores simplesmente saem dos meus algoritmos menos exatos. Vou postar abaixo os dois códigos, e se alguém pudesse tentar me ajudar eu ficaria muito grato!

Esse é o meu:

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sk
import numpy as np


n_estimators= 30
criterion = 'gini'
n_neighbors = 5
C = 2
max_iter = 1000
tol = 0.0000001
n_splits = 10


## PROCESSAMENTO QUE IRÁ GERAR: previsores (type: array) e classe (type: series)
dados = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\andrr\Desktop\Machine Learning\Bases de Dados\base01.csv')
classe = dados.iloc[:,4]
previsores = dados.iloc[:,1:4]
age_mean = previsores['age'].loc[previsores['age']>0].mean()
previsores['age'].loc[previsores['age']<0] = age_mean
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imp = imp.fit(previsores)
previsores = imp.transform(previsores)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
previsores = scaler.fit_transform(previsores)   

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

model1 = GaussianNB()
model2 = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model3 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=n_estimators, criterion='entropy')
model4 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, metric='minkowski', p=2)
model5 = LogisticRegression()
model6 = SVC(C=C)
model7 = MLPClassifier(verbose = True, max_iter=max_iter, tol=tol, solver = 'adam', activation = 'relu',momentum=0.9, learning_rate_init= 0.01)
b = np.zeros(shape=(previsores.shape[0], 1)) # Criação de uma matriz (2000, 1) composta por zeros
lista_de_modelos = [model1, model2, model3, model4, model5, model6, model7]
matriz_final=[]
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
resultados = []
for modelo in lista_de_modelos:
    model = modelo
    resultados_do_modelo = []
    for n in range(0,30):   
        kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state = n)
        for indice_treinamento, indice_teste in kfold.split(previsores, np.zeros(shape=(classe.shape[0], 1))):
            model.fit(previsores[indice_treinamento], classe[indice_treinamento])
            previsoes = model.predict(previsores[indice_teste])
            precisao = accuracy_score(classe[indice_teste], previsoes)
            print(precisao)
            precisao = str(precisao).replace('.', ',')
        resultados_do_modelo.append(precisao)
    resultados.append(resultados_do_modelo)
    
m2 = pd.DataFrame(resultados)
m2 = m2.transpose()
```

E esse é o do professor:
(Sim, ele tinha que tirar os comentários de cada um dos modelos para só então poder conferir as precisoes):

```
import pandas as pd

base = pd.read_csv('credit_data.csv')
base.loc[base.age < 0, 'age'] = 40.92
               
previsores = base.iloc[:, 1:4].values
classe = base.iloc[:, 4].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(previsores[:, 1:4])
previsores[:, 1:4] = imputer.transform(previsores[:, 1:4])

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
previsores = scaler.fit_transform(previsores)

import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

resultados30 = []
for i in range(30):
    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state = i)
    resultados1 = []
    for indice_treinamento, indice_teste in kfold.split(previsores, np.zeros(shape=(classe.shape[0], 1))):
        #classificador = GaussianNB()
        #classificador = DecisionTreeClassifier()
        #classificador = LogisticRegression()
        #classificador = SVC(kernel = 'rbf', random_state = 1, C = 2.0)
        #classificador = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, metric='minkowski', p = 2)
        #classificador = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=40, criterion='entropy', random_state=0)
        classificador = MLPClassifier(verbose = True, max_iter = 1000,
                              tol = 0.000010, solver='adam',
                              hidden_layer_sizes=(100), activation = 'relu',
                              batch_size=200, learning_rate_init=0.001)
        
        
        classificador.fit(previsores[indice_treinamento], classe[indice_treinamento])
        previsoes = classificador.predict(previsores[indice_teste])
        precisao = accuracy_score(classe[indice_teste], previsoes)
        resultados1.append(precisao)
    resultados1 = np.asarray(resultados1)
    media = resultados1.mean()
    resultados30.append(media)
    
resultados30 = np.asarray(resultados30)    
resultados30.mean()
for i in range(resultados30.size):
    print(str(resultados30[i]).replace('.', ','))
```

Eu tentei ver se essa diferença de precisão se dava devido à algum erro, mas nao pude encontrar nenhuma diferença. Se alguém me pudesse informar onde está o erro ou o que pode ser mudado eu ficaria muito grato!

Comment: Pode ser o caso do método de print ser diferente. Se você tiver comparando um resultado no data frame com os do professor, q tão em outro formato, o número de casa decimais default do print pode ser diferente mesmo.